# Can I spy on a mapDispatchToProps function with React Testing Library and Jest without losing implementation?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

We have just migrated from Enzyme to React Testing Library. In this transition we're finding almost everything easier to test, but we found a case we're not being able to test.

Every time an API request fails, we show a toast to the user, by calling an action.
As that part of the DOM is not being rendered, we are not able to search for the toast in the screen, but we could test that the action is being called at least.

However, no matter how I try to spy on that function, I can't manage to spy correctly.

Basically, my case is a connected component, and want to spy on an action, like this:

```js
// These actions are normally in a different file, but there is no difference
const increment = () => ({type: 'INCREMENT'})
const decrement = () => ({type: 'DECREMENT'})

// My component
const Counter = ({increment, decrement, count}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Counter</h2>
      <div>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <span data-testid="count-value">{count}</span>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({count: state.count})
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  increment,
  decrement,
}

// The connected component that I'm testing
const ConnectedCounter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```

And this would be the failing test:

```js
// render is the helper function that renders with the store. See implementation on codesandbox below.
test('can spy on action that was dispatched', () => {
  const mockIncrement = jest.fn().mockImplementation(increment)
  render(<ConnectedCounter increment={mockIncrement} />)
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('+'))
  expect(mockIncrement).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

I'd rather not lose the real implementation because of the way the actions are handled in the enhancers inside the store.

I have done a modification and add a failing test that shows my case in the codesandbox of all React Testing Library examples:

[https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ishizaka-spkk1?file=/src/**tests**/react-redux.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-ishizaka-spkk1?file=/src/__tests__/react-redux.js)

So, when I have a connected component with functions inside mapDispatchToProps, how can I spy on them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an RTL expert, but I think the suggestion here would be to change what you're trying to test.

Conceptually, you shouldn't be trying to verify that the component specifically happened to call `props.increment`.  Instead, you should be checking to see if the text content in the component changed from a '0' to a '1' after the click.  The focus should be on whether it's producing the right results, not on how that behavior is implemented.

Comment: That would be ideal. But in my case, the text that is changing is not being rendered in the test (it is in another part of the layout), therefore it cannot be found. That's why I want to be able to spy on the action.